# Can I do a server-side redirect to a subfolder and preserve url parameters of the original link?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-alias

I need to redirect links from external pages to an application into a subfolder.

My "old" links where like this:

```
 https://www.somepage.com/index.cfm?id=abc
```

Which I now have to change to:

```
 https://www.somepage.com/mem/index.cfm?id=abc
```

While I informed all users to update their links, I'm sure I will have to chase some for a while, so my idea was to try and setup a redirect server side. What I'm not sure is how to preserve the url parameter on the re-direct. Is something like this possible at all?

Thanks for some insights!

Comment: Which Web Server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `QSA` (Query String Appended) to preserve the query string.
Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /index.cfm$ /mem/index.cfm [QSA,L]
```